# How to change the order of dimensions of images data's shape for a neural network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, shapes, flatten

I have a greyscale images dataset that I want to feed into a neural network.

`x_train_grey.shape` is `(32, 32, 73257)`  so I understand it is `(dimension_x, dimension_y, batch_size)`. Because the images are greyscale, there is only one "depth" dimension.

However to feed this data to the neural network it needs to have this shape:`(batch_size, dimension_x, dimension_y)`. With `batch_szie` at the beginning.
How do I reshape it to this format, so that `batch_szie` comes before the x, y images dimensions?

Once this is done, I expect to be able to pass this into a neural network (the first layer being `Flatten()`), like so:
`Flatten(input_shape=(32, 32, 1)),`.

Cheers!

Comment: You can look into the `reshape` method in [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy.reshape)

Answer (score 0):

Solved! By passing the correct shape into `np.reshape()`.

I really should get to know `numpy` better, before getting into deep learning.